# Error: Invalid field Discount for SObject OpportunityLineItem

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I am editing the "Quote" visualforce page template and needed to add a column for Discount. This field gives the percent per-item on the OpportunityLineItem, much like Quantity.  I keep getting the error (in subject field) and can't figure why.

```
   <apex:repeat value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityLineItems}" var="line">
  <tr>
    <td>{!line.PricebookEntry.Name}</td>
    <td>{!line.Description}</td>
    <td ALIGN="center"><img src='{!line.PricebookEntry.Product2.URL_Picture__c}'/></td>             
     <td>{!line.Quantity}</td>

     <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.Discount}"/></td>

     <td><apex:OutputField value="{!line.TotalPrice}"/></td>
      </tr>
   </apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the Field level security for the Opportunity Product (OpportunityLineItem) Discount field. I checked a couple of Orgs and Discount isn't visible to any profiles by default.

The URL will be something like this: (You will need to change the server instance from cs7)

https://cs7.salesforce.com/p/setup/field/StandardFieldAttributes/e?id=Discount&type=OpportunityLineItem

Alternatively, get there with - *Your name* > Setup > App Setup > Customize > Opportunities > Opportunity Products > Fields > Discount > Set Field-Level Security.

Also, if your relatedTo list is being created in the backing controller via a SOQL query ensure that it is selecting the Discount field.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a custom field? Try with Discount__c

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to write a VF email template and am having the exact same issue with the OpportunityLineItem fields Discount and Subtotal.  I can safely say this is not a FLS issue, double checked it on both fields and they are visible to all profiles.

```
<apex:repeat var="opp" value="{!relatedTo.OpportunityLineItems}">
   <tr>
       <td>{!opp.Discount}</td>
       <td>{!opp.Subtotal}</td>
   </tr>
</apex:repeat>
```

I also double checked my data model using both SoqlX and Data Loader and both fields show up on the OpportunityLineItem object.

The only workaround I've been able to come up with that works for Discount is creating a percent formula field called Discount__c and setting it equal to the standard Discount field.

[Discount__c Field](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/497645aa-c891-4c83-a612-6a7ff105fd04/e0612003344e86030e59672dce10e785/res/ada31750-8137-4537-9bd3-405a58c60ed5/Discount__c.jpg?resizeSmall&width=832)

Subtotal on the other hand, cannot be referenced by a formula field, so I had to recreate the field.  This can also be used to create a Roll-Up Summary of the Subtotal field, since the standard Subtotal field can't be used.

[Subtotal__c Field](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s89/sh/6facc2de-2b45-410b-a7e3-4e355872978b/b4dbead8914346e2a6df0cb73088fe9c/res/a1452a64-a4b0-4957-a00e-652a4b9cc315/Subtotal__c.jpg?resizeSmall&width=832)

Once the new fields were created I was able to reference them in the email without any issues.  I don't see why this wouldn't work for a VF page as well.

Hope this helps, wish I could provide a better solution that simply recreating the fields.